# Feathersjs verify user via verifySignupShort pin code

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I am working on a proof of concept using feathersJS for signing users up via phone number and verifying via sms and pin https://github.com/morenoh149/feathers-chat-phone-signup-sms

Currently I get the following error

```
$ sh curls/user-verify.sh 118903
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   208  100   156  100    52  17067   5689 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17333
{
  "name": "BadRequest",
  "message": "Expected string value. (authManagement)",
  "code": 400,
  "className": "bad-request",
  "data": {},
  "errors": {
    "$className": "badParams"
  }
}
```

the api is using https://github.com/feathers-plus/feathers-authentication-management and I've done my best to adapt it to this use case. My curl looks like

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{ "action": "verifySignupShort", "value": 12345 }' \
http://localhost:3030/authmanagement
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs The value should be an Object with a `user` and `token`. Token should be a string as well.

```
{
    "action": "verifySignupShort",
    "value": {
        "token": "390494",
        "user": {
            "phoneNumber": "5005550006"
        }
    }
}
```

Docs: https://github.com/feathers-plus/feathers-authentication-management/blob/master/docs.md

Comment: now how should one get a jwt if they signup via phone number? jwt in verify response or some other endpoint?